# A simple issue of ListLinePlot ticks with table function

Tags: plotting, ticks

I need to plot a discrete linear function III(i)=i, so

```
III = Table[i, {i, 0, 1, .1}];

Y[x_] := x;

ListLinePlot[III, Ticks -> {Automatic}]

Plot[Y[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

The plot have ticks for each discrete step 0.1, so that  x-axis are multiplied ten-fold the  and the origin is displaced.

How i convert the discret plot in the same form of the continnum plot?

[image]

Comment: Look up `DataRange`.

Comment: III = Table[{i,i}, {i, 0, 1, .1}]; should do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [J. M. mentioned](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/108472/a-simple-issue-of-listlineplot-ticks-with-table-function#comment293520_108472), use `DataRange`

```
ListLinePlot[III, Ticks -> {Automatic}, DataRange -> {0, 1}]
```

> [image: Plot]